# IIS connection reset after redirecting http to https

Tags: iis, redirect

I'm getting a connection reset error in browsers when I redirect a URL from http to https. I'm trying to locate the issue and have looked in `C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` and see only `Timer_ConnectionIdle` errors in the log. From what I was able to find, those are not related.

There are no logs in the `FailedReqLogFiles` folder and I'm not seeing anything but access logs in the `W3SVC1` folder.

I'm completely lost on where to go from here. Here is my redirect rule.

**Match URL**
Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Regular Expressions
Pattern: `.*` and Ignore case

**Conditions**
Logical grouping: Match All
Input: {HTTPS}
Type: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: off

**Server Variables**
Blank

**Action**
Action type: Redirect
Redirect URL: `https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:0}`
Append query string: checked
Redirect type: Permanent (301)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet from `web.config` works for me.

```
<rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

The main difference between this and your configuration seems to be `HTTP_HOST` vs `SERVER_NAME`. I am using replacement pattern `R:1` whereas you're using `R:0`, but this can be explained by the way I've defined my match pattern as `(.*)` rather than `.*`.